# Website Contact Form with PHPMailer not sending messages through

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, phpmailer

I've deployed a site live however the contact form is not working. I made use of PHPMailer for the contact form as I needed smtp authentication for my web host (NameHero) to work. When I send a message through the contact form the form clears indicating that an action took place, however no email gets sent into my WebMail inbox. In my code when an email is sent, its supposed to display "Message Sent" however that doesnt happen. I'm not sure what exactly went wrong with my coded contact form however any help or advice indicating were I can correct my code would be greatly appreciated.

Below is a snippet of the html contact form

```html
                            <div class="col-12 p-0">
                                <form action="php/sendEmail.php" id="nexgen-simple-form" class="nexgen-simple-form">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="section" value="nexgen_form">

                                    <input type="hidden" name="reCAPTCHA">
                                    <!-- Remove this field if you want to disable recaptcha -->

                                    <div class="row form-group-margin">
                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 m-0 p-2 input-group">
                                            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control field-name" placeholder="Name">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 m-0 p-2 input-group">
                                            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control field-email" placeholder="Email">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 m-0 p-2 input-group">
                                            <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control field-phone" placeholder="Phone">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-12 m-0 p-2 input-group">
                                            <textarea name="message" class="form-control field-message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-12 col-12 m-0 p-2 input-group">
                                            <span class="form-alert"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-12 input-group m-0 p-2">
                                            <a class="btn primary-button">SEND</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
```

Here is my sendEmail.php file:

```html
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email'])){
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $subject = $_POST['subject'];
  $body = $_POST['body'];

  require_once "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
  require_once "PHPMailer/SMTP.php";
  require_once "PHPMailer/Exception.php";

  $mail = new PHPMailer();

  //smtp settings
  $mail->isSMTP();
  $mail->Host = "gamma.cloudr******.com";
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
  $mail->Username = "admin@djiv******.live";
  $mail->Password = "Brit2b******";
  $mail->Port = 465;
  $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";

  //email settings
  $mail->isHTML(true);
  $mail->setFrom($email, $name);
  $mail->addAddress("admin@djiv******.live");
  $mail->Subject = ("$email ($subject)");
  $mail->Body = $body;

  if($mail->send()){
      $status = "success";
      $response = "Email is sent!";

  }
  else {
      $status = "failed";
      $response = "Something is wrong: <br>" . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  }

  exit(json_encode(array("status" => $status, "response" => $response)));
}
?>
```

Comment: Test PHP code separately from javascript while testing; otherwise you can't tell which is causing the problem. If you're not getting either success or failed responses, it suggests your code is not being run at all so make sure it is before trying to debug it. You're forging the from address which will result in the messages either not being delivered or ending up in spam - see [the PHPMailer contact form example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/contactform.phps) for how to do that correctly. Set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;` so you can see what the server is saying.

Comment: `that doesnt happen`...so what _does_ happen then? None of the code you've shown would ever generate the text `message sent`, anyway...did you mean `Email is sent!`?

Comment: P.S. This will likely be useful, if you need to work out why it's not sending mail: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/SMTP-Debugging

Comment: @Synchro I tested the phpmailer code (sendEmail.php) via xampp server and it worked properly. I'm not sure what you mean by forging the from address... are you referring to  $mail->setFrom($email, $name); ?

Comment: @ADyson Sorry mate, I meant "Email is sent!"

Comment: `not sure what you mean by forging the from address`...well if your user inputs their address as `xyz@gmail.com`, for example, and then you send an email from _your_ mailserver claiming to be from that address, then clearly that's impersonation isn't it - because you didn't send it from their legitimate gmail account, you just used their email address as if you own it. Most mailservers receiving such an email will notice that the domain name of the From address and the domain name of the server it came from don't match, and assume it's a forgery/spam attempt, and block it.

Comment: (And indeed some SMTP servers may refuse to accept such a mail for sending, if they have any security built into it at that end, too.) Instead you should use an email matching the domain of the mailserver you're using (it needn't have an inbox, just `noreply@yourdomain.com` will be fine), and then you can (optionally) put the user-supplied email address into the email body and/or the Reply-To field.

Comment: Yes, that is forgery. Use reply-to as in the example